Unsaved Checkbox State with localStorage in Chrome and Edge
I'm trying to save and restore the state of a checkbox and other elements using localStorage when a user duplicates or closes the tab. It works well when I have just the checkbox, but as soon as I introduce additional elements, the checkbox state is not saved correctly in Chrome and Edge. Inspired by a similar issue discussed here, I created a version demonstrating the problem:
function save() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox1zaal1');
  var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  localStorage.setItem('checkbox1zaal1', checkbox.checked);
  localStorage.setItem('box', textarea.value);
}

function load() {
  var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox1zaal1'));
  document.getElementById("checkbox1zaal1").checked = checked;
  document.querySelector('textarea').value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('box'));
}

function wis() {
  location.reload();
  localStorage.clear();
}

load();

<input type="button" id="ReserveerButton1" value="save" onclick="save()" />
<input type="button" id="Wisbutton1" value="delete" onclick="wis()" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1zaal1">
<textarea>Hello, world!</textarea>

DEMO
Steps to reproduce the issue:

Navigate to the demo page.
Just check the checkbox.
Click the save button.
Duplicate the tab.

The checkbox on the duplicate tab is not checked.
What am I missing? Is this a known bug in Chrome and Edge, or is there another approach I can try to ensure that the checkbox state is saved correctly alongside the other elements?

@CBroe: "why parse this as JSON, when you never encoded it as JSON in the first place?" According to dfsq in his post, it's used to change the string type to a boolean. I just tried to copy his fiddle.

Okay, and what have you done so far to try and debug this? Have you verified what values got stored, which ones got read back?

@CBroe: I tried different form elements, and it seems to save and restore their values with no problem. When it comes to a checkbox, however, Chrome & Edge fail to display the stored data correctly.

So what does get stored? Go verify via your browser dev tools, and log the value of checked inside load to console.

@CBroe: I check the checkbox, duplicate the tab, and the actual checkbox on the page is not checked, although I have the following in the console: console.log(checked); // true That's weird!

It works fine for me in Chrome, with your above given demo URL. Doesn't matter if I reload the current tab, or open it again in a new one - the checkbox always takes the previously save-d state.

@CBroe: Please try it without editing the textarea.

That also works; but the textarea stuff is throwing errors - because the value you are storing for that, can not be parsed as JSON. So remove the JSON.parse for the textarea.

@CBroe: I'm afraid not. It doesn't display the checkbox saved state correctly. I'm using the latest version of Chrome on Windows and macOS. Please delete your browsing data and try again.

Even when I try in a private tab (so no existing browsing data history) - same results. Maybe you have some browser extension interfering on your end?

@CBroe: No extension. That's strange! I just open the demo page, check the checkbox, click the save button, and duplicate the tab. The checkbox is not checked in the new tab.

Based on the demo you provided, I did a test, but I did not reproduce the checkbox problem you described on Edge and Chrome. Please provide a reproducible demo or tell me more detailed steps to reproduce. In addition, what is your Edge version?

@kobewang: "Please provide a reproducible demo or tell me more detailed steps to reproduce." The demo is reproducible: Navigate to the demo page. Check the checkbox. Click the save button, and then duplicate the tab. The checkbox on the duplicate tab is not checked. Chrome: 126.0.6478.127 (Official Build) (64-bit), Edge: 126.0.2592.87 (Official build) (64-bit)

@CBroe Can reproduce on Chrome 126.0.6478.127 on Windows and OSX. But only for the initial load of the second tab after "right click -> Duplicate". Ie if I do a refresh in the second tab it sets the values correctly. I also fixed the errors with JSON.parse which didn't make a difference with that behaviour

@kobewang I can perfectly reproduce with the exact steps given above ... (Ie "duplicate tab" meaning "right click on the tab -> duplicate")

No need to parse json for textarea. document.querySelector('textarea').value = localStorage.getItem('box');. It solve  your issue

There is one major issue with your code: You are using JSON.parse without actually JSON.stringifying the values, you are trying to parse later on. This leads to an error, when you trying to parse the value for the textarea. This error can easily be seen, when you open the chrome developer tools ...
So I'd suggest to fix your load by getting rid of the JSON.parse
function load(){
    var checked = localStorage.getItem('checkbox1zaal1') === "true";
    document.getElementById("checkbox1zaal1").checked = checked;
    document.querySelector('textarea').value = localStorage.getItem('box');
}

But even with that error fixed, it still doesn't work as expected (at least with Chrome based browsers. It works with Safari). Not sure why it fails,though, because (at least for me) it only fails on the initial load in the new tab. Ie if I do a "Refresh" in the newly created tab it works as expected.
But I can get it to work if I do
setTimeout(load, 0)

instead of
load();

This seems like some sort of timing issue or race condition in the browser engine. Maybe someone with more insights can give an explanation here. With using the setTimeout we are actually not calling the load synchronously within the rendering process anymore, but only after the rendering is completed. This seems to make a difference here ...
It also seems strange that the checkbox is actually cleared on "Duplicate tab", because if I remove the call to load entirely, "Duplicate tab" restores the values of the inputs like they are in the source tab ... So maybe this is a conflict/timing issue between restoring the input-values by the "Duplicate" operations and updating the inputs from the script.  This assumption may also explain, why everything works as expected if one does a "Refresh" on the duplicated tab. And more strangely it also seems to work, if the textarea is not empty when saving or when I remove the textarea and all related code entirely ...
So this is probably not the canonical answer you are looking for. For me it seems more like a bug in Chrome (and derived browsers like Edge or Brave). Especially because it works as expected in non-Chrome browsers like Safari or Firefox and it also works in Chrome-based browsers when you do a refresh or just paste the url into a new empty tab. Maybe it's even depending on the version and/or OS version because it alledegly works for other users also in Chrome. You may try filing an issue with Chromium (but I suggest you fix the errors with JSON.parse first)

Your code works perfectly with latest Chrome on MacOS, of course if the script is placed after the other html elements (after the textarea) or at least the initial load() call is executed on DOMContentLoaded. What OS are you testing with?

@kikon I'm able to reproduce the issue with Chrome 126.0.6478.127 on MacOS ventura, Windows 10 and Windows 11.  But only in the specific situations I pointed out in the answer ...

And also on Edge 126.0.2592.87 on Windows 11

I filed an issue with the google issue tracker and they confirmed they are able to reproduce this issue for versions since 116  up to current stable and also for the versions in the future release channels beta, dev and canary

I'm not sure if this is a known bug, but this is a bug from Chrome's end. I'm assuming this is because this duplication feature hasn't been standardized and apparently their method of handling duplication is still not complete.
So, we'll resort to workarounds!
New Solution
<body>
  <input type="button" id="ReserveerButton1" value="save" onclick="save()">
  <input type="button" id="Wisbutton1" value="delete" onclick="wis()">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1zaal1">
  <textarea>Hello, World!</textarea>
  <script>
    // Treat this as a constant, in real app, you can use `const`
    // We're now limiting ourselves to es5
    var CHECKBOX_NAME = 'checkbox-' + Math.random().toString().substring(2, 8);
    var DEFAULT_TEXTAREA_VALUE = 'Hello, World!';

    function save() {
      var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox1zaal1');
      var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

      if (checkbox.checked) {
        localStorage.setItem('checkbox1zaal1', '1');
      } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('checkbox1zaal1');
      }
      localStorage.setItem('box', textarea.value);
    }

    function load() {
      var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
      textarea.value = localStorage.getItem('box') || DEFAULT_TEXTAREA_VALUE;

      var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox1zaal1');
      checkbox.name = CHECKBOX_NAME;
      localStorage.getItem('checkbox1zaal1') === '1' && 
        checkbox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    }

    function wis() {
      location.reload();
      localStorage.clear();
    }

    load();
  </script>
</body>

Apparently using a different name for checkbox is enabling the browser to load the value properly. Not to worry, although we're creating the checkbox name dynamically above, we can still keep track of it using a constant identifier.
N.B. Took the liberty to refactor, organize & clear out some parsing errors.
Previous Solution
Here's an attempt -
function load() {
  var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox1zaal1'));
  if (checked) {
    document.getElementById("checkbox1zaal1").click();
  }
  document.querySelector('textarea').value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('box'));
}

Instead of setting the checked attribute, we're triggering a click for them to get that element checked!
N.B.

You still need to fix JSON-parsing of your textarea value, I'm only addressing the checkbox state retrieval here!
This apparently still doesn't work in Edge. Seems as though using setTimeout there to execute load is as good a workaround as the next one!


Quite a complicated approach if the whole issue can be worked around with a simple setTimeout(load, 0) and maybe will be fixed in a near future release of chrome

I just refactored code to clean a few things up. Other than that, the only thing that is important here is to attach a unique name to the checkbox input. Don't think that's a complicated approach.
If the code overwhelms you, take the author's code and try adding the following one-liner to load function after the function's first line -
document.getElementById("checkbox1zaal1").name = 'checkbox-' + Math.random().toString().substring(2, 8);

No it's not overwhelming me, but setting random names to form inputs may not always be possible because typically, when one uses a name for an input, that name bears a certain semantics

ADD :
var as = document.getElementById('textbox').value
//Code to sent to discord webhook
sent(as)


What is sent supposed to be?

It like function for sending to discord webhook, I can't make it so u just add function itself for sending, handling and other

So what does dies have to do with this question?

I followed the steps you provided to reproduce the problem, but it did not reproduce it. But when I turned off the "Allow sites to save and read cookie data (recommended)" setting, I could reproduce the problem. So please enter "edge://settings/content/cookies" in the Edge address bar and check if this setting is turned off to cause this problem.

Disabling this setting prevents edge from writing to the local storage. But as OP verified, that writing to the localstorage works, this setting is obviously enabled ...

Problem:
You're trying to save and restore the state of a checkbox along with other elements using localStorage. While it works with just the checkbox, introducing additional elements (like a textarea) can lead to the checkbox state not being saved correctly in Chrome and Edge when duplicating tabs.
Cause:
A race condition exists between browser rendering and your JavaScript code. When you load data from localStorage (using the load function), the browser might render elements like the textarea before setting its value. This can overwrite the saved checkbox state in localStorage when you call the save function later.
Solution:
There are two approaches to address this:
Using setTimeout:
Wrap the call to the load function inside a setTimeout with a delay of 0. This ensures load runs after the browser finishes rendering:
function load() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var checked = localStorage.getItem('checkbox1zaal1') === 'true'; // No need for JSON.parse for booleans
    document.getElementById("checkbox1zaal1").checked = checked;
    var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
    textarea.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('box'));
  }, 0);
}

Using the storage event:
Listen for the storage event on the window object. This event fires whenever localStorage is modified. You can check for changes in the specific key you use for the checkbox and update its state accordingly:
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'checkbox1zaal1') {
    var checked = event.newValue === 'true'; // No need for JSON.parse for booleans
    document.getElementById("checkbox1zaal1").checked = checked;
  }
});

load();

Additional Points:
You can directly use localStorage.setItem('checkbox1zaal1', checkbox.checked) for storing boolean values (checked state) in localStorage.
Remember to clear localStorage when the user explicitly deletes data (using the "delete" button).

The upper half of this answer is just rephrasing my answer if a few days ago. And the part with the storage event doesn't make any sense with this question because it's not about synchronization and the storage event won't be called upon opening a new tab

:) Very common problem with vanilla js. We have to think three things. Change of UI, change of STATE, & if user save that state or not.
So I have update your code a little bit. Please let me know if need more explanation apart from comments
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Unsaved Checkbox State with localStorage in Chrome and Edge - Labground</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/lab.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" id="ReserveerButton1" value="save" onclick="save()">
<input type="button" id="Wisbutton1" value="delete" onclick="wis()">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1zaal1">
<textarea></textarea>
<script>
    const DOM_ELEMENTS = {
        checkbox: document.getElementById('checkbox1zaal1'),
        textarea: document.querySelector('textarea')
    }

    const EL_STATE = {
        checkbox: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox1zaal1')),
        textarea: localStorage.getItem('box')
    }


    function wis() {
        localStorage.clear();
        location.reload();
    }

    // Save
    function save() {
        localStorage.setItem('checkbox1zaal1', DOM_ELEMENTS.checkbox.checked);
        localStorage.setItem('box', DOM_ELEMENTS.textarea.value);
    }


    // Onload function.
    (function() {
        // Get checkbox state
        if (EL_STATE.checkbox === null) {
            EL_STATE.checkbox = false;
            localStorage.setItem('checkbox1zaal1', EL_STATE.checkbox);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('checkbox1zaal1', EL_STATE.checkbox);
        }
        // UI checkbox state
        DOM_ELEMENTS.checkbox.checked = EL_STATE.checkbox;


        // Get textarea state
        if (EL_STATE.textarea === null) {
            EL_STATE.textarea = 'Hello World!!!';
            localStorage.setItem('box', EL_STATE.textarea);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('box', EL_STATE.textarea);
        }
        // UI textarea state
        DOM_ELEMENTS.textarea.value = EL_STATE.textarea;

        // Listen on changes of the checkbox UI and UPDATE state each time the checkbox is change
        DOM_ELEMENTS.checkbox.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            EL_STATE.checkbox = event.target.checked;
        });

        // Listen on changes of the textbox UI and UPDATE state each time the value is change
        DOM_ELEMENTS.textarea.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
            EL_STATE.textarea = event.target.value;
        });
    })();

</script>
</body>

</html>


Why would this be a "very common problem"? Acutally it's not because this whole issue only happens in a very specific situation which is most probably an issue with the browser and not with the code ...

hey @derpirscher  My bad. I didn't put  "very common problem with JS" in quotes :) I mentioned that because we forgot basic process of JS engine, since most of us (including myself) we are using frameworks that do the job out of the box since we are all lazy :) .
I put this code in details to show why we need to update UI and STATE separated, without assuming that values are types by default.
